# What is the best way to delete or disable ( most expected) the field of a content type?

Tags: entities, features

We have several content types (features) on our Backend, now site Administrators (authors) and content managers need some field to be disabled when creating content. How I can manage it?
I heart about the 'field_permission' module but I'm not sure if that module can solve my problem.
What could be the best way to disable these fields? Is there some module or could some one explain where I should start?
Pseudo code are Welcome
Thank you in advance
Hermann

Comment: there is a big difference between disabled and deleted.
Could you specify which use case is yours ?

Comment: another question... which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: Hey Oleg,thy for your reply. So I prefer to disable them and we use drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do.

1. Find contents that have data for those fields you want to delete.(You can easily find it in DB)
2. Delete all contents found in step 1 or remove data from those contents.
3. Remove the field from content type.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your setup. If you dont want those fields anymore you can simply delete them off content type but if you want those fields to be available for certain roles then go with something like [field permission module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). Also, if you have those content type defined in features, I would recommend making changes to it first and then rebuilding the features.

Comment: Hey Ash, thx for your reply. I allready installed the field permission module. The problem is that for some roles the field is still enabled. So perfect will be that some content managers with role 'x' when creating a content from a certain type (admin->add content -> content type) should not even see that field. Currently that is not the case when using the field permission module. Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Have you rebuilt content permission? You should rebuilt content permissions after installing any content access module. Also I would recommend checking if there is any other content access module installed on site as it might be might be interfering with field permission module.

Comment: Hey Ash, I played a little bit around with the field permission module, it's possible to restrict field access and edit for certain roles. But Since the user 1 (admin) has no role on the site, it's not possible to restrict access to him. Is there another possibility? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yeah user 1 will have access to everything. Only a developer should have access to that user account. Every other user on site should be assigned a role. So I would suggest rather than giving client access to user 1 you should create a new user for them and assign them administrator permission. That way you will have full control over the field.

Comment: Hey Ash, thank you for your reply. we already has users roles (editors,...). So I gives for that specifics fields only access to the admin. Everything is working fine. But now I'm try to export those change with features, but in the production nothing is changed. more [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231300/missing-roles-component-for-a-content-type-on-features)